# Create Nested JSON object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Hello I want to create a JSON Object for storage resources in a post request in java script I have an input array value disk sizes for example below:

request1
input = [10, 20, 30]

```
 "storageResources": [
  {
    "stats": [
      {
        "name": "diskSize",
        "units": "GB",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "diskIopsConsumed",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "diskConsumedFactor",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stats": [
      {
        "name": "diskSize",
        "units": "GB",
        "value": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "diskIopsConsumed",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "diskConsumedFactor",
        "value": "NaN"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stats": [
      {
        "name": "diskSize",
        "units": "GB",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "diskIopsConsumed",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "diskConsumedFactor",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
],
```

request2:
input [10,20]

```
    "storageResources": [
  {
    "stats": [
      {
        "name": "diskSize",
        "units": "GB",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "diskIopsConsumed",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "diskConsumedFactor",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stats": [
      {
        "name": "diskSize",
        "units": "GB",
        "value": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "diskIopsConsumed",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "diskConsumedFactor",
        "value": "NaN"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Is the best way to do this with a function or can you send it by properties?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: And what do you want to do? Nested these two arrays?

Comment: Feels bad that it represent disk since with a unity... what will you do if they say that disk size is 512 MB? And are you sure it's not mixed with a GiB and not GB? Programmatically it should just be byte length and be represented in the view human friendly...

Comment: Those were two different types of requests one has two disks and the other has 3 disks.

Comment: @Endless that is just what the api takes

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.prototype.map to return a modified response

```js
$$text.oninput = evt => {
  let json = JSON.parse($$text.value)
  let result = json.storageResources.map(resource =>
    resource.stats.find(e => e.name == 'diskSize').value
  )
  
  console.log(result)
}

$$text.oninput()
```

```html
<textarea id="$$text">{"storageResources":[{"stats":[{"name":"diskSize","units":"GB","value":10},{"name":"diskIopsConsumed","value":0},{"name":"diskConsumedFactor","value":1}]},{"stats":[{"name":"diskSize","units":"GB","value":20},{"name":"diskIopsConsumed","value":1},{"name":"diskConsumedFactor","value":"NaN"}]},{"stats":[{"name":"diskSize","units":"GB","value":30},{"name":"diskIopsConsumed","value":0},{"name":"diskConsumedFactor","value":1}]}]}</textarea>
```